# Should I email old supervisor about my progress?

Tags: advisor, career-path, professorship, communication

I might collaborate with an old supervisor in the future and would like to keep in touch. Is it a good idea to send an email to him about the progress I've made in my career?  Also, what's the best way to approach this? I feel like emailing just to talk about myself is a bit narcissistic -- is it?

Comment: I often send (links to) preprints and ask for comments (if it's related to what my advisor did).  I also sometimes ask questions and go back to visit him.  Though the visits and contact, we eventually began thinking about a couple of projects together.

Comment: Isn't that what LinkedIn is for? Let them pester everyone to join to learn about what you're up to.

Comment: Email old advisors on a regular basis. You can update them on your progress and they can update you on theirs. Seems less narcissistic to ask what they've been up to. They might also send along opportunities like review articles, etc.

Answer (score 42):

I just did that, and I often do. If I'm honest, I don't do that as much as I should. Anyway, unless told otherwise, which, imho, would be rare, that should be acceptable/desirable.

Of course, you won't just talk about your stuff, but ask about his/hers. You do have common interests after all.

Professors are people too! There is no secret in talking to a fellow professional that you know. And, of course, never send a professor a lengthy message.

Be polite, be direct, and informative...

Answer (score 28):

As a supervisor, still being in interaction (on their own  initiative sometimes) with former students, MSc & PhDs is one of my greatest pleasures.

Still planning (long after supervision) joint work, collaborative projects with your supervisor should be welcome quite positively. Even for sheer information. Good supervisors, teachers, most of the time, do this job to **elevate** or **guide**. They usually are happy when they have succeeded. They are often happily surprised. Apparently, this does not happen so often, and they cannot know. Students forget.

You can cope with narcissism by "sharing" or "returning" your progresses to a person you estimate for what s/he brought to your line of research. Whenever this happens to me (so very rare), I am happy.

Comment: If you liking to show your former supervisor how far you got now gets considered being "narcissistic", it shows that something's really broken in the general value system. Of course, profs like to hear about their students succeeding! And it's perfectly normal and healthy to talk about that to people that will be happy seeing you succeed, whether your parents, grandparents, good friends and profs. It's not showing off to people who don't know you and have no reason to delight in your successes.

Comment: @Captain Emacs "narcissistic" was in the OP. And this is an "inner feeling", for which I tried to offer reformulation. I was slightly concerned with the "send an email [because] I might collaborate" part. Thankfulness could be free of charge.

Comment: @ Laurent Duval Yes, indeed, I referred to the OP using the term, not you. I find this term overused these days. But you have an additional point that the OP is not entirely spontaneous here.

Answer (score 21):

I enjoy getting periodic updates from former students. It's nice to think that I've made a positive impact in their lives, and it's nice to hear that they are doing well professionally. And I've sent periodic updates to my advisor every now and then.

As for the best way to approach it, and it not coming off as narcissistic, I'd simply recommend that you keep it brief. Don't delve into lengthy details; professors are busy people! Keep it short and simple. Of course, you can always wrap up with a line like this:

> If you're interested, I could give you the particulars. Feel free to get in touch.

Then wish them a good day and include your contact information in your signature block.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, do it.  Of all supervisors you've had, there's just this one that you're thinking of reaching out to.  That means this supervisor is special.  If this is the only supervisor you're caring to follow up with, then that's a compliment.

> Also, what's the best way to approach this?  I feel like emailing just to talk about myself is a bit narcissistic -- is it?

The best way to avoid making it sound like you're only talking about yourself is to avoid only talking about yourself.  Mention someone else, too.  For example, the supervisor you're mentioning.

Let them know that one of the topics you really want to bring up, because this topic is quite important, is this: thank you.

Really, ex-supervisors don't get told that nearly enough.